# Binary expansion of a positive integer and its half

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, binary

I quote from Chapter 1 (page 29) in Weissman's "An Illustrated Theory of Numbers":

> If $x$ is a positive integer, write $\mathrm{bits}(x)$ for the number of bits in the binary expansion of $x$. Recall that $\mathrm{bits}(x) = \lfloor \log_2(x) \rfloor + 1$; it follows that $\mathrm{bits}(\lfloor x/2 \rfloor) \leqslant \mathrm{bits}(x) - 1$.

I don't understand why this is true; I'm reasoning as follows.

If $x = 1$, then $\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor = 0$. So we have $\mathrm{bits}(\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor) = \mathrm{bits}(x)$.

If $x \geqslant 2$, then there exists a unique $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
k \geqslant 2 \quad \text{and} \quad 2^{k-1} \leqslant x < 2^k,
\end{equation*}
that is $\mathrm{bits}(x) = k$. Therefore, we have $2^{k-2} \leqslant \frac{x}{2} < 2^{k-1}$, and the number of bits in the binary expansion of $\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor$ is exactly $k - 1$, that is $\mathrm{bits}(\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor) = \mathrm{bits}(x) - 1$.

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not wrong, but your result does not contradict the assertion that $$\operatorname{bits}(\lfloor x/2\rfloor)\le\operatorname{bits}(x)-1\,:$$ after all, if $a=b$, then it’s certainly also true that $a\le b$. However, I have to admit that I don’t see why the author chose to state the weaker conclusion, since the stronger one follows easily from his own calculations:

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{bits}(\lfloor x/2\rfloor)&=\lfloor\log_2(x/2)\rfloor+1\\
&=\lfloor\log_2x-1\rfloor+1\\
&=\lfloor\log_2x\rfloor-1+1\\
&=\operatorname{bits}(x)-1\,.
\end{align*}$$

Yes, he really ought either to restrict himself to integers $x\ge 2$ or mention that $x=1$ is an exception, though in practice I doubt that the oversight will cause much trouble.

Comment: I understand that my result does not contradict the assertion if $x$ is an integer greater than $1$, but maybe the author should have excluded the case $x = 1$.

Comment: @Paolo: Fair enough; I wasn’t sure, because we’ve had people who really did think that there was something wrong with stating $a\le b$ when in fact $a=b$. Yes, he probably should explicitly state that $x=1$ is an exception.

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I don't see why I did that either.  Even though it's technically correct, I'll add this to the Errata with an acknowledgment.  And I'll improve the treatment in the second edition... thank you!

Comment: @Marty: You’re very welcome!